# import from vs import in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is `from foo import *` equivalent to `import foo`? Plese help.
The question is about python 2.7

Comment: If you mean in effect - both will load the whole module `foo` (and everything it loads and...), the former will just not require you to use `foo` namespace to access its globals (e.g. you'll be able to access `foo.property` as `property` alone)

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules

Answer (score 0):

No,
When you use `import foo`, to call a function from from this package you have to do : `foo.my_function()` whereas with `from foo import *` you can write `my_function()` directly

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is more in style of use. But I would not use `from foo import *`. I think it's better to be specific on what you need to import:

```
from foo import package_0
from foo import package_1
from foo import package_2 
# etc
```

However, you need to add additional import every time you need a new package which can be avoided if you use `import foo`. But in that case you need to prefix every package inside of it with  `foo`:

```
foo.package_0.some_method()
foo.package_1.another_method()
```